# Linux desktop/display very slow and inefficient

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, performance, cpu

I've always lived under the impression that Linux is way faster than Windows (I'm a C++ developer, and that's my primary gate to Linux), but now I'm having trouble with performance and I need help.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with Dell XPS 15, and the desktop interaction is dead-slow, to the point that I can't watch a youtube video without lagging through it all the time, and I'd like to understand the reason.

**Note on CPU usage:** Nothing is consuming my CPU. The CPU is 4 cores and 8 threads, and I can see in `htop` that nothing consumes the CPU.

**Facts:**

1. Some websites (javascript-based front-end) consume the CPU very strongly, an example is [Binance trading website](https://www.binance.com/tradeDetail.html?symbol=ETH_BTC). Clicking on a price takes seconds to have it fill the buy/sell fields.
2. I have a big machine with 16 cores for calculations. When I `ssh -X` to Qt Creator with my Ubuntu to develop, response latency (in my local network) is extremely slow (takes the text cursor a while, 0.5 second, to respond to my actions). When I use Windows and ssh through MobaXTerm, I get instantaneous and super-fast responses.
3. I have NVidia display card, and I use driver `nvidia-390`.
4. Whether I use Firefox or Chrome or Brave. Having many tabs is a catastrophe and watching videos is impossible. I have to constantly keep killing tabs to make the browser survive.
5. There's an apparent horrible management of priorities in my system. Say I start Slack chat, and it eats 1 CPU due to some animations. That is completely sufficient to slow down the whole computer. I mean, there are 3 other CPUs. Why do all CPUs have to be at peace for the computer to work peacefully without endless lags?
6. All the lags are graphics-related. Terminal stuff are fine.

Is this a common problem or is it just me and my laptops? (I have another laptop with Intel display with the same issues).

Where do I start to solve this problem? Please advise.

---

EDIT:

Requested output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 750M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell GK107M [GeForce GT 750M]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_390, nvidia_390_drm
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Done...